# window.resizeTo() not working in jquery terminal popup window

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, popup, jquery-terminal

**Problem:** I have been working on my own jquery terminal, and the terminal is hosted in a popup window of the website. I have tried to create a command that changes the popup windows width and height on command, but it doesnt work.

**What I have tried:** I have tried the resizeTo() method, and the window.resizeTo() method, but it still doesnt work.
I feel like im using the syntax wrong, but im not too sure, I have seen some examples already on resizeTo() and have a fair understanding how it works.
This is the code I have so far for the command in my jquery terminal:

```
win: function(wid, hei) {
     window.resizeTo(wid, hei) 
},
```

This is the code I used to make the window popup:

```
function diff() {
    var win = window.open('about:blank',"", "width=1100, height=600, border=0",'directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no');// <-- include the URL 
    var url = "https://myurl.com" 
    var iframe = win.document.createElement('iframe')
     
    iframe.style.top = iframe.style.bottom = iframe.style.left = iframe.style.right = 0
    iframe.style.position = "fixed"
    iframe.style.width = "100%";
    iframe.style.height = "100%";
    iframe.style.border = "none";
    iframe.src = url
    win.document.body.appendChild(iframe)
}
```

Comment: We need more context here please. Is this code running within the popup or in the parent that spawned the popup?

Comment: The code is running within the popup

Comment: Do you open the PopUp with `window.open(url, title, "height=<number>,width=<number>");`?

Comment: Also if you reply to someone in the comment you need to ping him (type @ and start typing then name and you can pick the full name from the context menu) otherwise he will not know that you replied. You don't need to do this only when you comment on someone's question or answer to notify the person. This is exactly the same as on Social Media.

Comment: @jcubic yes and no, I added some extra stuff in the function for opening the popup, I updated it so you can see. And oh well, my bad, im just kinda new here and to be honest, I have no social media.

Comment: So the problem is that you're trying to resize the iframe, not the window. You need to use `window.parent.resizeTo(win, hei)`. can I ask why you need an iframe? Can't you put the URL into the first argument on the open function?

Comment: Also, remember to indent your code, it's hard to read if you don't put whitespace before nested blocks of code.

Comment: @jcubic Ah ok, that makes sense thanks for the help, and the reason its in an iframe is because im trying to get the terminal in an about:blank page, and the code I used to summon the popup window does it perfectly. You are right tho, I could use it in a normal page.